# MaskedTextBox for dates?

Tags: maskedtextbox

*ERROR: .ArgumentException: The value representation '3/7/2021' does not match the mask.*

I am using the MaskedTextBox (from xceed wpftoolkit). I would like the user to input and see a clean date as `"__/__/____"` in typical US fashion as MM/dd/yyyy.

The following works correctly for "3/7/2021",

```
 <xceed:MaskedTextBox Width="240" FontSize="28"  IncludeLiteralsInValue="True"  Value="{Binding EffectiveDateFrom, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" ValueDataType="{x:Type s:DateTime}" Mask="0/0/0000" />
```

but fails when the mask is changed to

Mask="00/00/0000"

So how is a mask written that will allow for both dates as "12/30/1999" or "3/7/2021" ?

Thank you for any help on this. (Note: I am not opposed to any solution: I have seen some suggestions to use the DatePicker instead. Any thoughts?)

TIA

Comment: Just guessing here but the normal convention would be #0/#0/0000

Comment: @RetiredGeek Nope :) System.ArgumentException: 'The value representation '3/7/2021' does not match the mask. (Parameter 'value')'.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [documentation](https://doc.xceed.com/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit%7EXceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MaskedTextBox%7EMask.html) what you want is: 90/90/0000
If you use #0/#0/0000 you would have to type the leading spaces!
[image]

HTH

Comment: @RetiredGreek I concur. But: System.ArgumentException: 'The value representation '3/7/2021' does not match the mask. (Parameter 'value')'.  I have to wonder if ValueDataType="{x:Type s:DateTime} isn't messing this up. But it would be nice to talk directly in DateTime (not strings). Oh well. Thanks.